# ColdFusion : Record Deletion

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a crypto bot that is working well.  But every once in awhile I get a data delete error.  It usually occurs when I reload the page or an auto reload happens and the record was deleted just prior I think.  And new data was not populated in or it has that #deleted# in table?

On each load it just puts new prices in. and deletes those from 30mins ago.  Just trying to avoid creating huge price database.  So i just delete the 30 mins prior.  But get this error every once in awhile. ColdFusion 2016 : MS Access

> Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record is deleted. 
> The error occurred on line 4.

```
<cfquery name="trdel" datasource="kickin_crypto">
    delete * from bot_data
    where prtime <= #createODBCDateTime(timethirty)#
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Add a `select count(*)` query beforehand and only attempt the delete if that result is greater than 0.

Comment: Added... But still get error. Is it even something as simple as the 2nd query is half a second later?  Perhaps tidy up... only delete above the 5 minute mark or something?

Comment: If you just *google the error* there's plenty of stuff about it. Looks to me like you have multiple concurrent requests trying to delete the same record, and the the latter one(s) are reporting back "it's already gone". A coupla things here. First: stick a lock around the delete query so yer never trying to delete it more than once at a time. Secondly: Access is not fit for purpose in a web environment. It's only designed for single-user access. I recommend you use a DB that's fit for purpose.

Comment: I just created a separate call every 30minutes, And took things out of the loop.  So it just does it once every 30mins separately on a scheduled task.  Fixed. No errors.  The loop was looping over deleted records. Access works fine for the load. Easy to work with for 20+ yrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a separate scheduled task 30minutes. Fixed.  Does it once... Doesn't loop over deleted records.